Citect SCADA 2018 - MODNET - Read Coils - Exception Code: Illegal data address
I have a problem with reading coils from a device, the rest of registers I am reading fine.
I added InitVar =1, InitVarType = 1 and in equipment editor I have a digital variable tag with address 01.
Best Regards
In WireShark I can see that citect sends this packet to the device:
.000 0001 = Function Code: Read Coils (1)
Reference Number: 0
Bit Count: 16
And in return I get exception like this:
.000 0001 = Function Code: Read Coils (1)
Exception Code: Illegal data address (2)
Why does citect sends reference number as 0 instead of 1?
I tested MODNET2 and MODNET3 with the same result.

Suspect section 4.4 of the Modbus spec is relevant. The spec uses registers in the range 1-x but what is sent over the wire is 0-(x-1) (i.e. the register number - 1). Unfortunately this gets confusing because different systems implement this in different ways (see "When 40001 Really Means 1, or 0 Really Means 1 " in this article).

I know this, in citect there are 4 different protocol variants Modnet, Modnet1/2/3 they differ in the lowest coil (0 or 1) address and range of bits (0-15, 1-16) The leading 0 in address points to reading coils. No matter with variant I choose, citect always sends request for 16 bits starting from 0.

The general recommendation is to check the device if coils are configured and in which address. If no coils are configured, then they can't be read, or coils can't be read outside the configured address space.

I tested reading coils using another software, and it works in WireShark I can see that this program sends "Reference Number: 1". Only Citect is sending request "Reference Number: 0"
